# Pass index to vue componnent has not the expected values

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is my component:

```
<template>
    <span class="pt-3">
        <GoodMacroElement v-for="goodMacro in goodMacroData" :macro="goodMacro" :index="counter++" class="row mt-3"></GoodMacroElement>
    </span>
</template>

<script>
import GoodMacroElement from "./GoodMacroElement"

export default {
  components:{
    GoodMacroElement
  },
  name: "goodMacros",
  data(){
    return {
      name: 'GoodMacros',
      goodMacroData: null,
      counter:0
    }
  },
  beforeMount() {
    this.goodMacroData = window.GOOD_MACROS;
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

I'm trying to pass a number  that start from 0 using the prop named `index`, to  the child component

```
<GoodMacroElement v-for="goodMacro in goodMacroData" :macro="goodMacro" :index="counter++" class="row mt-3"></GoodMacroElement>
```

But when I check `index` value on each GoodMacroElement the the first has  index = 909¿?¿?¿ ,how I cam make it to  make this value start from 0?

Answer (score 2):

Use the `index` provided by Vue itself.

`<div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="item.name"></div>`

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

 createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        goodMacroData: [
          {name: 'macro A'}, {name: 'macro B'}
        ]
      }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div v-for="(goodMacro, index) in goodMacroData" :key="goodMacro.name">
    {{ index }}: {{ goodMacro.name }}

  </div>
</div>
```

**Reason:**

When you use reactive variables in templates, and the variable is mutated, Vue will re render the template for you.

In your example, you were using the reactive var `counter` in the template. This means when anything changes the value of `counter`, Vue will re render the template, and your `v-for` loop.

The issue is, you were *mutating* `counter` *in* the loop - with `counter++`

So every time Vue renders the list, the underlying reactive data is changed, and Vue has to re render the list again, re updating the `counter` and so on.   Each time `counter` starts at the value it was at the end of the last render.

You can see here - pressing the button simply runs `counter++` and you can see the list re render and all the counts go up.

```js
const { createApp } = Vue;

 createApp({
    data() {
      return {
        counter:0,
        goodMacroData: [
          {name: 'macro A'}, {name: 'macro B'}
        ]
      }
    }
  }).mount('#app')
```

```html
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>

    <div id="app">
      <div v-for="goodMacro in goodMacroData" >
        {{ counter++ }}
      </div>
      
       <button @click="counter++">
          increment counter
      </button>
    
    </div>
```

You probably had some warnings about maximum recursion etc in the console as its an infinite loop.

Using the built in `index` counter, you do not mutate anything thus Vue does not re render.

Comment: Could you also explain why? It's quite important, for both OP and future users. Let me know if you'd rather have me do it.

Comment: Yup - sorry, will update the answer